# Limit Approaching an Eigenvector for Non-diagonizable Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I noticed that for any linear transformation -- with at least one eigenvector with a non-zero eigenvalue -- repeatedly applying the transformation to a non-zero vector approaches an eigenvector. That is to say for matrix $A$ with eigenvectors $v_1,...,v_k$ (kind of hand-wavy limit here)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n \vec{x}=a\vec{v_i}, a\in \mathbb{R}$$
This is trivial when $\vec{x}$ is in the span of the eigenvectors since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n \vec{x}=A^n(a_1\vec{v_1}+...+a_k\vec{v_k})=a_1\lambda_1^n\vec{v_1}+...+a_k\lambda_k^n\vec{v_k}$$
and the limit will get closer to the span of the eigenvector with the largest $\lambda$

What confuses me is that choosing an $\vec{x}$ outside the span of the eigenvectors -- even one perpendicular to the space of eigenvectors -- will also approach one of the eigenvectors. Can a formal reason be given for this?

Two transformations that exhibit this behavior apparently are
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\ 
1 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
with 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional eigenvector space respectively. (maybe errors here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, your statement is incorrect.  What you should say instead is that
$$
v = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A^nx}{\|A^nx\|}
$$
will generally be an eigenvector, assuming that this sequence converges.  Note that this sequence will not necessarily converge!  For a simple example, take $A = -1$.

That being said: it will work "most of the time".  In fact, this is precisely what the [power iteration method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) does.